# Can't connect on Dart debug through virtualbox

Tags: dart, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm on windows, but on my Virtualbox I have one debian server.
I have create a Dart example and run it with:

`dart run --pause-isolates-on-start --observe`

With this i can connect to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8181/XDFGgXmZ5Xc=/devtools/#/?uri=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8181%2FXDFGgXmZ5Xc%3D%2Fws
```

But this link don't work!
When I try to access even inside the Virtualbox with the W3M (command line browser) there is no output.
I have checked for open ports and the port 8181 is open.

Can you guys tell me some ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the bind-address since the default are `localhost` which means only programs running inside your VM can get access to the observatory.

From `dart help run`:

```
--enable-vm-service=<[<port>[/<bind-address>]]>    Enables the VM service and listens on the specified port for
                                                   connections (default port number is 8181, default bind address is
                                                   localhost).
```

If you want to make the observatory to every single network interface on your machine, you can change the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` instead. Be sure you don't allow this to be externally accessed from the internet. Alternative, you can specify the IP of the network interface you want the observatory to listen on.

```
dart run --pause-isolates-on-start --observe --enable-vm-service=8181/0.0.0.0
```